# R programming (extract same element matched with first column)

Tags: r

I have below list:

> head(input)

```
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6

1  A  1  2  3  4  5

2  B  1  2 NA NA NA

3  C  3  5 NA NA NA

4  D  3 NA NA NA NA

5  E  4  5  6  1  8
```

and I would like to get below results (extract all V1 elements matches to unique element from V2~V6):

```
1   A   B   E

2   A   B   

3   A   C   D

4   A   E   

5   A   C   E

6   E       

8   E
```

I was trying to write code in R, but I keep getting errors.. Can you please help with this code?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what kind of errors have you been getting? can you show us your work? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to `gather` to 'long' format, then `arrange` the rows, grouped by 'val', create a sequence column and `spread` to 'wide' format

```
library(tidyverse)
gather(df1, key, val, -V1, na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
      arrange(val, V1) %>%
      group_by(val)  %>% 
      mutate(rn = paste0("Col", row_number())) %>%
      select(-key) %>% 
      spread(rn, V1) 
# A tibble: 7 x 4
# Groups:   val [7]
#    val Col1  Col2  Col3 
#  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1     1 A     B     E    
#2     2 A     B     NA   
#3     3 A     C     D    
#4     4 A     E     NA   
#5     5 A     C     E    
#6     6 E     NA    NA   
#7     8 E     NA    NA
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), V2 = c(1L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 4L), V3 = c(2L, 2L, 5L, NA, 5L), V4 = c(3L, NA, NA, NA, 
6L), V5 = c(4L, NA, NA, NA, 1L), V6 = c(5L, NA, NA, NA, 8L)), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6"), class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
```